# Changing to a standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking at an example problem in my textbook and I'm lost as to how they got the standard basis.

$B = \{1,x,x^2\}$ and $C = \{1+x, x+x^2, 1+x^2\}$ of p. Then find the coordinate vector of $P(x) = 1+2x-x^2$ with respect to $C$.

Then they have: Observe that the coordinate vector for $C$ in terms of $B$ are

$[1+x]_B = [1,1,0]$

$[x+x^2]_B = [0,1,1]$

$[1+x^2]_B = [1,0,1]$

These are column vectors

How did they get these coordinate vectors?

Comment: I do not understand the question clearly... Is it possible for you to edit this a little bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using $B = \{ 1, x, x^2 \}$ as a basis means that you can think of those elements as the column vectors $[1,0,0]$, $[0,1,0]$, and $[0,0,1]$.

So in the basis $B$,

$[1,0,0]$ represents $1(1) + 0(x) + 0(x^2) = 1.$

$[0,1,0]$ represents $0(1) + 1(x) + 0(x^2) = x.$

$[0,0,1]$ represents $0(1) + 0(x) + 1(x^2) = x^2.$

And so,

$[1,1,0]$ represents $1(1) + 1(x) + 0(x^2) = 1+x,$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at two different bases of the vector space of polynomials with degree at most $2$. The first basis $B=\{1, x, x^2\}$ consists of the monomials. In this basis we have the obvious coordinates
$$
[a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2]_B = \pmatrix{a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2},
$$
since $a_0$ is the coefficient of $1$ (the first basis vector), $a_1$ is the coefficient of $x$ (the second basis vector) and $a_2$ is the coefficient of $x^2$ (the third basis vector).

Now you have another basis, namely $C=\{1+x, x+x^2, 1+x^2\}$ again consisting of three polynomials. From the above oberservation we immediatly have
\begin{align}
[1+x]_B &= \pmatrix{1 \\ 1 \\ 0}, &
[x+x^2]_B &= \pmatrix{0 \\ 1 \\ 1}, &
[1+x^2]_B &= \pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ 1}.
\end{align}

The difficult part is going in the other direction, expressing a given polynomial in terms of the basis vectors of $C$. I will show you one example:

We want to find the coefficients $c_1, c_2, c_3$ such that
$$
x^2 = c_1 (1+x) + c_2 (x+x^2) + c_3 (1+x^2).
$$
We expand the terms and group by powers of $x$ to obtain
$$
x^2 = (c_1+c_3) + (c_1+c_2) x + (c_2+c_3) x^2.
$$

Now comparing coefficients (we can to that since $B$ is a basis) we have
\begin{align}
0 &= c_1+c_3, \\
0 &= c_1+c_2, \\
1 &= c_2+c_3.
\end{align}
The only solution of this system is $c_1=-\frac 1 2, c_2=c_3=\frac 1 2$, thus
$$
x^2 = -\frac 1 2 (1+x) + \frac 1 2 (x+x^2) + \frac 1 2 (1+x^2)
$$
and we found
$$
[x^2]_C = \pmatrix{-1/2\\1/2\\1/2}.
$$